# How to install SQL Server Profiler as part of VS.NET 2012 install

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012, installation, sql-server-profiler

I installed VS.NET Professional 2012 months back and it installed SQL Server 2012 Express, but it appears I may have missed the option that installs SQL Server Profiler. So I'd like to go back and add it, but I can't figure out how. When I run the VS.NET setup, it gives me "Modify", "Repair" and "Uninstall". If I selected "Modify", I get 6 check-marked items: Blend for Visual Studio, LightSwitch, MFC for C++, Microsoft Office Developer Tools, Sharepoint developer tools and web developer tools (all of which are checked).

I tried running the MS SQL Server install by double-clicking it in Programs and Features, but it pops up a little dialog with Add, Repair and Remove links, but clicking add (to add features) has it asking me for the install media and I can't find a directory on the VS.NET DVD that it's happy with.

Thanks.

Comment: By the way does SQL Express 2012 management studio come with the extended events UI? That will replace profiler at some point anyway so you could give that a whirl instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Express Editions of SQL Server don't have the Profiler.  You need at least the Standard Edition.  For some sufggested alternatives (none of which I have used) try Googling "SQL Server 2012 Express Profiler"

Comment: It also comes with developer edition which is considerably cheaper than standard!